# How do I make an opaque control on a partly transparent form?

Tags: delphi, transparency

I want to make a half-transparent form but I want to put a panel on it which will not be transparent. How do I do that?

Comment: The one and the only api that supports variable translucency on a window is `UpdateLayeredWindow` (W7 and before), in which case you perform all the drawing (including non-client area), and which does not quite fit VCL's paint scheme (not criticizing it). For practical purposes I'd say this would be either not possible or quite difficult.

Comment: `UpdateLayeredWindow()` is available "W2K and after" instead of "W7 and before".

Comment: There is another option that does not involve `UpdateLayeredWindow()`. Move the panel to a separate borderless captionless `TForm`.  You can then set the main `TForm` to `AlphaBlend=True` and `AlphaBlendValue=...` as desired, then position the second opaque `TForm` on top of it. If the user moves the main `TForm`, just move the second `TForm` accordingly.

Comment: @Remy - Sure (the 'W7 and before' applied to whole sentence). What I was thinking was, W8 seems to have support for layered windows for even child windows, maybe it would be easier to achieve the same effect with W8 without using UpdateLayeredWindow (with SetLayeredWindowAttributes).

Comment: Even though W8 introduces support for layered child windows, I imagine that a child on a semi-translucent parent cannot override that translucency for itself. A layered window is rendered to an off-screen bitmap, so the parent window would be opaque when the child is rendered, then the finished parent bitmap would be rendered on-screen translucently as needed. I could be wrong, since I haven't tried W8 yet, but I don't see how it would be possible to have an opaque child on a translucent parent. Even if it were, it would certainly not be backwards compatible with W2K-W7.

Comment: @RemyLebeau After thinking for a while about possible "hacks" I figured this is indeed the best option. The other one is to create a normal panel, put draw a screenshot of everything behind it onto it. But this is even trickier. So thanks for that.